# How to convert static HTML template to drupal theme

Tags: theming

Is there any tools available to convert html template to drupal theme and is there any modules that make drupal 7 theming much easier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such tool that converts HTML to Drupal theme. But there are services where we can create some kind of Drupal theme with basic `regions` & `templates`.

Some modules you can try

1. [Themer](http://drupal.org/project/themer) *6.x only*
2. [Theme developer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer)
3. [Skinr](http://drupal.org/project/skinr)

[Theming Drupal 6 and 7](http://drupal.org/theme-guide/6-7)

[Modules for theming](http://drupal.org/node/646298)

A nice screencast for a beginner 
[Introduction to Theming Basics for Drupal 7](http://drupalize.me/videos/introduction-theming-basics-drupal-7)